# Protractor failed to start test with firefox

Tags: angular, firefox, protractor, e2e-testing, jasmine2.0

I can not start the test with protractor on firefox version 56.0.1.
my protractor version is 5.1.2

```
exports.config = {
    allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
    specs: [
        './e2e/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
    ],
    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'firefox'
    },

    directConnect: true,
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4444/',
    framework: 'jasmine',
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
        print: function() {}
    },
};
```

this is the error:

```
[00:02:20] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[00:02:20] I/direct - Using FirefoxDriver directly...
[00:02:27] E/launcher - Unable to parse new session response: {"value": {"sessionId":"e9d08604-1d7e-4870-85d7-4e09a2248ffa","capabilities":{"acceptInsecureCerts":false,"browserName":"firefox","browserVersion":"56.0.1","moz:accessibilityChecks":false,"moz:headless":false,"moz:processID":5804,"moz:profile":"C:\\Users\\s\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rust_mozprofile.sWpsKwszgKSw","pageLoadStrategy":"normal","platformName":"windows_nt","platformVersion":"6.1","rotatable":false,"specificationLevel":0,"timeouts":{"implicit":0,"pageLoad":300000,"script":30000}}}}
[00:02:27] E/launcher - WebDriverError: Unable to parse new session response: {"value": {"sessionId":"e9d08604-1d7e-4870-85d7-4e09a2248ffa","capabilities":{"acceptInsecureCerts":false,"browserName":"firefox","browserVersion":"56.0.1","moz:accessibilityChecks":false,"moz:headless":false,"moz:processID":5804,"moz:profile":"C:\\Users\\s\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rust_mozprofile.sWpsKwszgKSw","pageLoadStrategy":"normal","platformName":"windows_nt","platformVersion":"6.1","rotatable":false,"specificationLevel":0,"timeouts":{"implicit":0,"pageLoad":300000,"script":30000}}}}
    at WebDriverError (C:\Users\s\WebstormProjects\Co\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:27:5)
    at doSend.then.response (C:\Users\s\WebstormProjects\Common_IDE\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:445:19)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.createSession (C:\Users\s\WebstormProjects\Co\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:777:24)
    at Function.createSession (C:\Users\s\WebstormProjects\Co\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\firefox\index.js:640:55)
    at Direct.getNewDriver (C:\Users\s\WebstormProjects\Co\node_modules\protractor\lib\driverProviders\direct.ts:112:25)
    at Runner.createBrowser (C:\Users\s\WebstormProjects\Co\node_modules\protractor\lib\runner.ts:225:39)
    at q.then.then (C:\Users\s\WebstormProjects\Co\node_modules\protractor\lib\runner.ts:391:27)
    at _fulfilled (C:\Users\s\WebstormProjects\Co\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\s\WebstormProjects\Co\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\saeed\WebstormProjects\Co\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13)
    at C:\Users\s\WebstormProjects\Co\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:556:49
    at runSingle (C:\Users\s\WebstormProjects\Co\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
[00:02:27] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
```

do you have any idea how to solve this problem . (it it work normally with chrome but shows empty page with firefox)

Comment: Have you tried running the `webdriver-manager` commands as stated by the error message?

Comment: yes i have run webdriver-manager update but still i have this  error:E/launcher - Unable to parse new session response:{...} /WebDriverError: Unable to parse new session response:{...}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With geckodriver, you'll need to add marionette to the capabilities:

```
capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'firefox',
    'marionnette': true
},
```

UPDATE: There is a [open issue #4253](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4253) introduced in Protractor 5.1.1 . The workaround is to manually replace `directConnect` with `seleniumAddress` and manually start `webdriver-manager` as specified in the bug:

> The solution is to use selenium standalone when testing with Firefox.
>   The latest version of the selenium standalone server is compatible
>   with Protractor's selenium JS bindings and with geckodriver. You can
>   update and launch the standalone server with
>
> ```
> webdriver-manager update 
> webdriver-manager start
> ```
>
> and set `seleniumAddress: http://localhost:4444`

Comment: Sorry about that. There was a bug introduced in protractor 5.1.1 that I had mistakenly thought was fixed. I have edited my answer with the workaround.

Answer (score 0):

If you are opting for directconnect then you dont need to specify the **base url and don't need to start explicitly the webdriver server**.

```
exports.config = {
    allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
    specs: [
        './e2e/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
    ],
    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'firefox'
    },

    directConnect: true,
    framework: 'jasmine',
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
        print: function() {}
    },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, running it with 'sudo' did not work.
I had to change file permissions and then ran it without sudo.