# Firefox 57 does not load geckoservice in Selenium during end-to-end testing

Tags: selenium, firefox, protractor, geckodriver

I am trying to load Firefox to test my web application using selenium. I am getting `SessionNotCreatedError: Unable to create new service: GeckoDriverService` error when I specify firefox in the `capabilities`. Here is how it looks like:

```
var config = {
 sauceUser: process.env.SAUCE_USERNAME,
 sauceKey: process.env.SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY,
 framework: 'jasmine2',
 capabilities: {
  browserName: 'firefox',
  version: '57.0', 
  'screenResolution': '1920x1440'
 },
 specs: [
  '*.spec.js'
 ],
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
   showColors: true,
   defaultTimeoutInterval: 300000,
   print: function() {}
 },
  params: {
     defaultTimeout: 15000
 }
};
```

Here are details of my environment:

```
OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64bit
Firefox: Quantum 57 64 bit
Selenium: 3.7.1
webdriver-manager: 12.0.6
gecko driver: 0.19.1
Protractor: 5.2.0
```

When I ran my protractor End-to-End test cases it throws this error:

```
[13:14:58] E/launcher - SessionNotCreatedError: Unable to create new service: GeckoDriverService
Build info: version: '3.7.1', revision: '8a0099a', time: '2017-11-06T21:07:36.161Z'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.10.0-38-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_151'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/home/dev/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:546:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (/home/dev/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:509:13)
    at doSend.then.response (/home/dev/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:441:30)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.createSession (/home/dev/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:769:24)
    at Function.createSession (/home/dev/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/firefox/index.js:521:41)
    at createDriver (/home/dev/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:170:33)
    at Builder.build (/home/dev/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:632:16)
    at Local.getNewDriver (/home/dev/node_modules/protractor/built/driverProviders/driverProvider.js:53:33)
    at Runner.createBrowser (/home/dev/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:195:43)
    at q.then.then (/home/dev/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:339:29)
    at _fulfilled (/home/dev/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/home/dev/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/home/dev/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
[13:14:58] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
```

I tried using updated versions of *selenium* and *gecko driver* but that did not help either.

I added `marionette: true` but still getting the same error. I also tried `"javascriptEnabled": true, "acceptSslCerts": true` but with no success.

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/46762357/6205848

Answer (score 0):

It work for me when using geckodriver@1.10.0 and Firefox 57.0 (64 bits).

Comment: It might be helpful to list down your environment and the steps you took to make it work. But put that in a comment, not an answer :)

Comment: Hey @casvaart Here is my environment Windows 10, Firefox 57.0 (64 bits), Geckodriver 1.10.0, and JDK 1.8.0. I found above problem when using Geckodriver in earlier version but it can work well when updating to version 1.10.0.