# Process exited with error code 199 - unable to launch Firefox from protractor

Tags: firefox, jasmine, protractor

Having trouble to launch Firefox browser from Protractor. getting error
E/launcher - Unable to create new service: GeckoDriverService
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to give details of how to reproduce your problem?  E.g. see [Protractor failed to start test with firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46746046/3744182) or [Firefox 57 does not load geckoservice in Selenium during end-to-end testing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47401348/3744182) which show the sort of information that you should include in your question to increase your chances of getting help.

Answer (score 0):

Most probable reason is  your driver version and browser are mismatched.

I'm using geckodriver-v0.28.0.exe and browser version is 83.0 (64-bit)

Config:

```
jvmArgs: [
        '-Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=./src/driver/geckodriver-v0.28.0.exe'
  ],
directConnect: false,
multiCapabilities: [
    {
      browserName: 'firefox'
    }
  ],
```